# Laravel, Date range filter between two column

Tags: jquery, laravel

Hello i would like to filter date range from two different column, here is my current filter date :

```
$(document).ready( function(){
         $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                function (settings, data, dataIndex){
                    var datepicker_to = $('#datepicker_to').datepicker("getDate");
                    var datepicker_from = $('#datepicker_from').datepicker("getDate");
                    var startDate = new Date(data[20]);

                    if (datepicker_from == null && datepicker_to == null) {return true; }
                    if (datepicker_from == null && startDate <= datepicker_to) {return true; }
                    if (datepicker_to == null && startDate >= datepicker_from) {return true; }
                    if (startDate <= datepicker_to && startDate >= datepicker_from) {return true; }
                    return false;
                }
            );

            $('#datepicker_from, #datepicker_to').change(function() {
                    tableMediaOrder.draw();
                });
            });
```

so far im only able to filter date range form one column which the column that being filtered is column `Date(data[20]);` which is `created_at` column, is there a way to filter date range between two column like for my case is `periode_start` and `periode_end`?

here is the column :

[image: periode_start and periode_end]

thank you!.

UPDATE :
here is my controller.php :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        if(auth()->user()->is_admin){
            $data = MediaOrder::get();
        }else{
            $data = MediaOrder::memberOf(auth()->user()->group_id)->get();>get('group_idUser'))->get();
        }
        return DataTables::of($data)
                ->addIndexColumn()
                ->addColumn('action',function($row){
                    $btn = '<a style="margin:5px" href="javascript:void(0)" id="viewMediaOrder" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="View" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm button1 viewMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i class="fa fa-eye mr-1"></i>View</a>';


                    if(!$row->isdisabled){
                        $btn = $btn.'<a style="margin:5px" href="javascript:void(0)" id="editMediaOrder" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-warning btn-sm button1 editMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i class="fa fa-pencil mr-1"></i>Edit</a>

                        <a style="margin:5px" href="javascript:void(0)" data-toggle="tooltip" id="disableMediaOrder"  data-id="'.$row->id.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm button1 disableMediaOrder" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"><i class="fa fa-power-off mr-1"></i>Disable</a>';

                    }

                        return $btn;
                })
                ->rawColumns(['action'])
                ->make(true);
    } else {

        \Meta::set('title', 'Media Order');
        $groups = Group::all();
        $media_order = DB::table('media_order')->get();
        $moo = MediaOrder::get();
        $users = User::orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
        return view('media-order.index')->with(compact('users','moo','groups'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your controlelr code

Comment: i already update my question, but mostly i using jquery for my filter, not from my index

Comment: So you need filtering on datatable side not server side right ?

Comment: yes something like that

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this

```
$query->whereDate('periode_start', '>=', $datepicker_from)
->whereDate('periode_end', '<=', $datepicker_to);
```

Now you get filter date range between two column